# JBoss Clustering and Lighttpd Load Balancing displaying inconsistent behaviour

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, load-balancing, lighttpd

**PROBLEM**

We have two JBossAS 4.2.3 installed on separate machines and they are clustered. We also make use of Lighttpd that acts as load balancer, and is placed between our Tomcat servers (the Tomcat servers are not clustered) and the JBoss servers. Once all servers are up and running, the application runs flawlessly. If I bring down one JBoss server, the requests are redirected to the other server, as expected. My problem starts after I logout of the application. On trying to re-login into the application, I get an exception that says, Tomcat cannot connect to the server that was brought down.

**SERVER SETUP**

1. Machine01 - Tomcat7
2. Machine02 - Tomcat7
3. Machine03 - JBoss 4.2.3
4. Machine04 - JBoss 4.2.3
5. Machine05 - Lighttpd 1.4.28

**OTHER INFORMATION**

- All machines use Ubuntu 12.04 OS.
- JBoss machines are clustered.
- The EAR is dropped in the `all/deploy` folder.
- The JBossAS are started using the following command - `./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -c all --partition=SomePartitionName &> /dev/null &`.
- Tomcat7 run as a service, hence they are started as `sudo service tomcat7 start`.
- The Lighttpd is configured to work as a load balancer for the JBoss machines.
- The following the mod_proxy configuration on lighttpd:

  ```
  server.modules += ( "mod_proxy" )
  proxy.balance = "fair"
  proxy.server = ( "" => (( "host" => "Machine03", "port" => 1100 ),
                         ( "host" => "Machine04", "port" => 1100 ))
  ```
- The `jndi.properties` have the following entry

  ```
  java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
  java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
  java.naming.provider.url=Machine05:80
  ```

Unable to figure out why, after I bring down a machine and logout from the application, the Tomcats do not have a proxy-reference to the JBoss machines anymore.

Comment: How are you managing session? Sticky non-sticky?

Comment: Just to clarify again, the Lighttpd is used as a load balancer for the JBoss machines and not the Tomcat machines. Hence, in the current set-up the two Tomcat manage their own sessions and they are not clustered nor their sessions sync'ed. The Tomcat's behave as independent servers, talking to a single JBoss cluster.

Comment: @Rishabh I am not sure if this helps.... UNLESS your application is stateless, I would ask you to review the deployment architecture - based on your description above, if Tomcat instance goes down, then you have lost user session information, hence there is no known state for the user. I am sure you have a good reason for this... but as an architect, in a "stateful application" my focus would be on maintaining user state even if one of the state-machines goes down.

Comment: Now looking at the problem described by you... it is clear that somehow the lighttpd is not able to recognize the status of underlying JBoss Cluster for new sessions. Have you attempted creating multiple new sessions from different browser clients to see if your experience is any different? What I mean is... try creating bunch of new sessions from different clients to see if you get "Cannot Connect" errors. Hope this leads you to a solution.

Comment: Hi smallworld, our ear consists of stateless session beans so I'm not worried about session at jboss. As far as tomcat is concerned, we would implement session replication when we work on their clustering. Even if I connect using only a single tomcat I face the above issues. Tomcat clustering, session replication is the next step. For now I am stuck at making jboss work properly. To put it simply, why would Tomcat try to connect to the JBoss that has already been brought down? That would mean that the HA feature in JBoss is not working. I have re-checked the configuration hundred times now.

Comment: @Rishabh HA is a complex architecture and based on details outlined in your notes, it is very difficult for me to exactly pin point where things could be going wrong. Clustered HA JBoss is supposed to multi-cast messages to advertise its availability and the proxy/load-balancer is expected to manage distribution of workload based on its knowledge of who is available to process the request. All I can tell you is that your lighttpd proxy is not able to detect downed JBoss in your scenario. See page 21/22 of http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/pdf/Clustering_Guide.pdf

Comment: And one final note: if I understand it right, you are accessing session beans from your JBoss into your Tomcat (within your JSP tier) to render response to user's request. There is a good possibility that you are dealing with JNDI lookup caching here - i.e. "caching some stale references to stateless session beans" within your Tomcat tier, and trying to access them. To validate this hypothesis, you may try removing the lighttpd proxy from the mix. You may want to read upon a little on this by googling "jndi lookup caching"

Comment: @smallworld: I got rid of the lighttpd and tried accessing the cluster directly. The issues persists. The 'jndi lookup caching' makes sense. Will work on that and update you.

Comment: @Rishabh good to see hypothesis validated. At this point, I can almost assure you that you are dealing with jndi lookup caching and stale references issues. Good luck solving that part!

Comment: Thank you @smallworld. As stated by you the "jndi lookup caching" was the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it solved now. Thanks to [smallworld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155320/smallworld) for pointing me to the right direction.
What was happening was that we were caching the remote interfaces obtained from the jndi lookup. Now from what I understand, this remote interface points to only one particular server from the cluster. (We were thinking that the remote interface would be smart enough to identify that the server is down. Looks like that smartness is somewhere with the initial context when you do the lookup). So once the server is brought down, any ejb call made to that remote interface would land up connecting to the server that was brought down. So to solve it, we stopped caching the remote interface and do a lookup every time we need the services of that EJB. If the any server is down, the lookup would return the remote interface of the server that is up and running. With this the cluster works flawlessly! So, guys your code should look something like this:

```
    // Some where at class level we have the following map declared
    private static final Map remoteEJBHashMap = new HashMap(100, 0.9f);

public static final <T> T getEJBInterface(String jndiLookupName) {
    String jndiName = jndiLookupMap.get(jndiLookupName);
    T ejbInterface = null;
    //T ejbInterface = (T) remoteEJBHashMap.get(jndiLookupName);
    //if (ejbInterface == null) {
        try {
            ejbInterface = (T) ctx.lookup(jndiName);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        //remoteEJBHashMap.put(jndiLookupName, ejbInterface);
    //}
    return ejbInterface;
}
```

The commented lines are the ones that caused the issue. Now the only thing left for me to research is a better solution to this if there is any.